# Handling complex authorization in spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a spring MVC web app using pre- and post- authorization method annotations.

I have a particular method in one of my services that needs to apply much more complex authorization logic.

I notice there's a `PermissionsEvaluator` interface, but that appears to be intended for a more global approach to permissions rather than per-module.  I suppose one could write an implementation that delegated to module-specific `PermissionsEvaluators`, but that seems like a lot of work.

Additionally, I'd be doubling up on a lot of effort.  The authorization decision is based on intermediate state during the actual processing.  If I used the `PreAuthorize` mechanism, I'd be generating that state once for authorization, then again "for realsies".

Is there a standard spring exception I can throw from my service layer directly?  Is there some other approach I should consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [AccessDeniedException](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDeniedException.html). It is thrown internally by Spring Security when a pre- or post-condition evaluates to false. By default it generates a 403 Forbidden page.